# Counting distinct number of users from beginning

Tags: mongodb

I have a MongoDB aggregation pipeline that has been frustrating me for a while now, because it never seems to be accurate or correct to my needs. The aim is to count the number of new unique users each day per chatbot, starting from the very beginning.

Here's what my pipeline looks like right now.

```
[
            {
                "$project" : {
                    "_id" : 0,
                    "bot_id" : 1,
                    "customer_id" : 1,
                    "timestamp" : {
                        "$ifNull" : [
                            '$incoming_log.created_at', '$outcome_log.created_at'
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                },
            {
                "$project" : {
                    "customer_id" : 1,
                    "bot_id" :  1,
                    "timestamp" : {
                        "$dateFromString" : {
                            "dateString" : {
                                "$substr" : [
                                    "$timestamp", 0, 10
                                    ]
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                },
            {
                "$group" : {
                    "_id" : "$customer_id",
                    "timestamp" : {
                        "$first" : "$timestamp"
                        },
                    "bot_id" : {
                        "$addToSet" : "$bot_id"
                        }
                    }
                },
            {
                "$unwind" : "$bot_id"
                },
            {
                "$group" : {
                    "_id" : {
                        "bot_id" : "$bot_id",
                        "customer_id" : "$_id"
                        },
                    "timestamp" : {
                        "$first" : "$timestamp"
                        }
                    }
                },
            {
                "$project" : {
                    "_id" : 0,
                    "timestamp" : 1,
                    "customer_id" : "$_id.customer_id",
                    "bot_id" : "$_id.bot_id"
                    }
                },
            {
                "$group" : {
                    "_id": {
                        "timestamp" : "$timestamp",
                        "bot_id" : "$bot_id"
                        },
                    "new_users" : {
                        "$sum" : 1
                        }
                    }
                },
            {
                "$project" : {
                    "_id" : 0,
                    "timestamp" : "$_id.timestamp",
                    "bot_id" : "$_id.bot_id",
                    "new_users" : 1
                    }
                }
]
```

Some sample data for an idea of what the data looks like...

```
{ 
    "mid" : "...", 
    "bot_id" : "...", 
    "bot_name" : "JOBBY", 
    "customer_id" : "U122...", 
    "incoming_log" : { 
        "created_at" : ISODate("2020-12-08T09:14:16.237Z"),
        "event_payload" : "", 
        "event_type" : "text" 
        }, 
    "outcome_log" : { 
        "created_at" : ISODate("2020-12-08T09:14:18.145Z"), 
        "distance" : 0.25, 
        "incoming_msg" : "" 
        } 
    }
```

My expected outcome is something along the lines of:

```
{     
    "new_users" : 1187.0,     
    "timestamp" : ISODate("2021-01-27T00:00:00.000Z"),     
    "bot_id" : "5ffd......." 
},
{
    "new_users" : 1359.0,
    "timestamp" : ISODate("2021-01-27T00:00:00.000Z"),
    "bot_id" : "6def......."
}
```

Have I overcomplicated my pipeline somewhere? I seem to get a reasonable number of new users per bot each day, but for some reason my colleague tells me that the number is too high. I need some tips, please!

Comment: Just a note, you can nest functions, i.e. `{timestamp: { "$dateFromString": { "dateString": { "$substr": [{ "$ifNull": ['$incoming_log.created_at', '$outcome_log.created_at'] }, 0, 10] } } }}` works also

Comment: Do you really want the `$first` timestamp (which depends on the order of documents) or rather `$min`?

Comment: Can you please provide some sample data and expected result?

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit I didn't know that `$first` was document order dependent! Should I do a `$sort` before using it?

Comment: Please edit your question for additional input rather than as comment. And please provide 2-3 more documents.

Comment: Yes, either `$sort` and `$first` or just `$min`

Comment: Your `created_at` value is a `Date` object, using `$dateFromString` is pointless. as it expects a **string**.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit The reason I use `$dateFromString` on `$substr` is because I want to remove the time from the `Date` object and only store the actual date in the final aggregation, so as to not also complicate the `$group : timestamp` stage. It's worked so far! Also, I have edited my question to include the sample data and expected outcome.

Answer (score 0):

I have really no idea what you are looking for.

"The aim is to count the number of new unique users each day per chatbot, starting from the very beginning."

What is "new unique users"? What do you mean by "starting from the very beginning"? You ask for count per day but you use `{"$group": {"_id": "$customer_id", "timestamp": { "$first": "$timestamp" } } }`

For me your grouping does not make any sense. With only one single sample document, it is almost impossible to guess what you like to count.

Regarding group per day: I prefer to work always with `Date` values, rather than strings. It is less error prone. Maybe you have to consider time zones, because UTC midnight is not your local midnight. When you work with `Dates` then you have better control over it.

The `$project` stages are useless when you do `$group` afterwards. Typically you have only one `$project` stage at the end.

So, put something to start.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
   {
      $set: {
         day: {
            $dateToParts: {
               date: { $ifNull: ["$incoming_log.created_at", "$outcome_log.created_at"] }
            }
         }
      }
   },
   {
      $group: {
         _id: "$customer_id",
         timestamp: {$min: { $dateFromParts: { year: "$day.year", month: "$day.month", day: "$day.day" } }}
      }
   }
]);
```